# Copy/Paste not working on a Linux based shell

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

After is searched a lot on the internet, am here in search of the solution for the below problem.

Thanks in advance for helping hands!

I have a Linux-based shell (not bash shell but similar) where am using a 3rd part code tinyrl (from clish/klish) to read the input from the shell.

Below is the function from tinyrl that reads the user input and returns it which is further used to display on the shell.

```
tinyrl_vt100_getchar(const tinyrl_vt100_t *this)
{
    unsigned char c='\0';
    int istream_fd = -1;
    FILE *sfd = this->istream;

    if (!sfd) return VT100_ERR;
    istream_fd = fileno(sfd);

    /* Just wait for the input if no timeout */
    if (this->timeout <= 0) {
        if ((c = getc(sfd)) == EOF) {
            if (feof(sfd))
                return VT100_EOF;
            else
                return VT100_ERR;
        }
        return c;
    }
    /* Set timeout for the select() */
    fd_set rfds;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(istream_fd, &rfds);

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = this->timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int retval = -1;
    while (((retval = select(istream_fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 0) &&
        (EAGAIN == errno));
    /* Error or timeout */
    if (retval < 0)
        return VT100_ERR;
    if (!retval)
        return VT100_TIMEOUT;

    if ((c = getc(sfd)) == EOF) {
        if (feof(sfd))
            return VT100_EOF;
        else
            return VT100_ERR;
    }
    return c;
}
```

**Problem description**

When an input is given by copy-pasting the content, only one character appears and after pressing any key (like an arrow, space, backspace, letter, etc) the remaining content appears on the shell.
Example:
If we have copied “abc def xyz” content, then when pasted on the shell it displays only “a” and when any key is pressed it displays remaining content.

The expectation is it should not be required to press any key to complete the paste operation.

**The solution is I have already tried**

Using read() in place of getc(). This actually resolves the copy-paste issue but it causes other problems that keystroke value like "[C, [D, etc" getting printed on the shell when the cursor is moved rapidly through the content we pasted on the shell.
So this solution is not useful.

Thanks!

Comment: One problem is the comparison in `if ((c = getc(sfd)) == EOF)` because `c` is `unsigned char` and `EOF` is usually defined as `(-1)` so the result of the comparison will never be true.

Comment: control is not even reaching EOF situation. Let's say I remove if condition and keep only `c = getc(sfd)` still same issue is observed.

Comment: combination of `select()` with `read()` works well as both takes `int fd` in argument, but with `select()` and `get()` combination there is a difference that `getc()` takes `FILE fd`. Can I cause the problem? What could be the solution?

Comment: Mixing low level I/O functions like `select()`, `read()` and `write()` with the C stream I/O functions can be a bad idea because the buffering gets in the way. Setting to unbuffered mode (`_IONBF`) using `setvbuf` might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot "Ian Abbott". Setting to unbuffered mode helped.